# Where to change 30 seconds for grub on forced reset

Tags: boot, grub2

When I start my Ubuntu there is this splash screen:

[image]

and i got rid of it by changing this line:

```
from
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
to
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

so it skips the grub right away.

But if I force reset/power off the machine I get this screen:

[image]

Now with 30 seconds countdown...

My question is where is this coming from, which file? I want to change it and it's not in `/etc/default/grub`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found it on my own

in file `/etc/grub.d/00_header`

on line 333 there is a costant

```
set timeout=${GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT:-30}
```

and you can override it in `/etc/default/grub` file like this

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
```

and now even if i force reboot/power off it will skip the grub

Do not forget to call `sudo update-grub` after editing to apply new settings

Comment: you could also try in your grub setting `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=N` not sure which one of those overwrites which. But if the setting in the grub file works it's probably better than changing the header file.

Comment: I think that wouldn't work because of this `if [ "\${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=${GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT:-30}
else EOF` in header it is strictly set so i think it would be overwritten. But i will try it out now and let you know

Comment: Damn it seems that you were right....it takes that value...i will change my answer. (done)

Answer (score 3):

lewis4u's answer works, but is more complicated than necessary.

Simply add the following line to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=5
```

I used `5` seconds, but you can use whatever value you want.

Comment: @mbp sorry but what is more complicated than necessary? Your answer is 100% identical... except you've set the time to 5 seconds and mine is 0

Comment: @lewis4u - I misread your answer.  I assumed you also made changes to line 333 of `/etc/grub.d/00_header`.